# Postgres query cache analyzing table basis?

Tags: postgresql, query-cache

The PostgreSQL application I'm currently on is solely based on functions. Every request from the front end maps to a PostgreSQL function call. Many of these functions call other functions. Like: web application server calls function A, function A calls function B, function C queries data from table D and E and so on.
Now, I'm running into big performance issues. While anyway trying to optimize the functions themselves, I'm wondering if query caching might help me.

The problem is: The cache mechanism should analyze which tables are actually concerned by a certain function call and thus refresh or invalidate the cache entry if one of these tables is updated.

Let me give you an example. Consider functions like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.pets_get_all(user_id integer)
$BODY$
SELECT dogs_get_all($1) AS dogs
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

The dependent functions being

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.dogs_get_all(user_id integer)
$BODY$
SELECT id, name FROM dog WHERE user_may_read_dog($1,dog_id)
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;


CREATE FUNCTION public.user_may_read_dog(user_id integer, dog_id integer)
$BODY$
SELECT owner_id = $1 FROM dogs WHERE dog_id = $2
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Let's say, for the first time `pets_get_all` is executed with 1337 as the parameter, the query works like normal and it returns.

```
+----------+-----------+
| ID       | Name      |
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | Bella     |
| 2        | Max       |
+----------+-----------+
```

So, for the next time `pets_get_all(1337)` is executed, the query will be fetched from the cache, the inner functions won't be executed and thus, it will be pretty much faster.
However, when the dog with the id 2 is updated, the cache entry will be updated too (taking some time of course). So, the cache will be always up to date. Of course, changes in the dog with the id 3 will not affect the cache entry for pets_get_all(1337)`, since the user the id 1337 may not read dog 3.

Does such a thing exist?

I had a rough look into "PostgreSQL Query Cache" ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pqc-dev ) However, it seems outdated and the expiration of cache entries is only time-based (which is not what I want).

Comment: I think you are better off fixing the performance problems — keeping your cache synchronised is going to involve more pain than finding the real problem

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between materialization and query plan caching.

Answer (score 2):

## Clearing up confusion about `IMMUTABLE`

> So, for the next time pets_get_all(1337) is executed, the query will be fetched from the cache, the inner functions won't be executed and thus.

That's not true. In fact, even in the same query the result isn't *typically* "cached": which as far as I know isn't a correct description of what's going on. It's more of a planner reference trick. There is certainly no transactional [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) going on here. These are two different concepts and there is nothing about a function call *especially* one which *may* be inlined that implies what you're assuming.

`IMMUTABLE` and even `STABLE` does imply that the query-**plan** itself is cached. This means that future calls within the same transaction will not be re-planned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION stable_foo()
RETURNS void
AS $$
  SELECT pg_sleep(1);
$$
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE;


CREATE FUNCTION immutable_foo()
RETURNS void
AS $$
  SELECT pg_sleep(1);
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Just looking at the timing:

```
\timing

-- these will take 2 seconds.
SELECT * FROM immutable_foo() AS a, immutable_foo() AS b;
SELECT immutable_foo(), immutable_foo() FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x);
SELECT immutable_foo()::text || immutable_foo()::text;

-- these will take 1 second.
SELECT immutable_foo() FROM ( VALUES (1),(2) ) AS t(x);

-- but declared as `STABLE` like foo(), it takes two seconds.
SELECT stable_foo() FROM ( VALUES (1),(2) ) AS t(x);
```

So only under specific circumstances in the *same* query will a function call get optimized out.. However, you'll *never* find a situation where this happens across statement boundaries..

As far as I know, the contexts for which an immutable function is optimized away are undocumented. Historically, this is even something experienced [folks have struggled with](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/113-How-to-force-PostgreSQL-to-use-a-pre-calculated-value.html) and there is a general *try it and see* mentality as to whether or not the optimization takes effect.

```
BEGIN;
  SELECT bar();
  SELECT bar();
END;
```

I prefer to think of `IMMUTABILITY` in terms of what it permits, things such as (a) functional indexes, (b) functional index predicates (c) check constraints and the like. They all require a function to return the same arguments given the same inputs to make sense -- and they'll check that they're given an immutable function. But, it doesn't follow that there is memoization that operates in the transaction, session, or server.

## PgPool 2

If you do need an actually query-cache you should consider checking out [PgPool 2](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgpool2.git;a=summary) which is the industry-method of doing this.

It's essentially middleware (or a forward-cache depending on your age).

## As it applies to you

Writing a system to exploit undocumented query optimizations is a *bad idea*. You're better of not doing this at all, stepping back and just using SQL. Sure, the *results* of a complex query are not cached. But the buffered heap fetches and plans are. If it's in the same transaction it's working off the same data.

I would find weak links in your application and ask questions about how to make them faster. What you're doing seems something akin to pre-optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, I think this might partly be a misunderstanding: I was not asking for an explanation of the current behavior, but for a way to achieve that results of queries *would* actually be stored. I will definitely have a look into PgPool II!